# Video on pageload

Tags: files

Hey is there a possibility to make a video automatically load on pageload (website) on Drupal 7 ? I mantion that I have installed Drupal 7 video module and I posted a video on my website but I do not know how to make it start on site load (if there is a posibility). Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1):

On the [Video Module](http://drupal.org/project/video) page, there is a link to documentation:

[External Documentation](http://video.heidisoft.com/documentation/welcome-video-module-documentation)

which when clicked leads you to some General Help:

[General Help](http://video.heidisoft.com/documentation/general)

which leads to this picture:

[image]

Have you tried checking the `Automatically start video on page load` option there?

Comment: yes I know about that check, but I do not want that, all I want to do is for example when I type www.mywebsite.com on the internet browser I want the video to start automatically before the user login menu . I belive it's an onload function but I don't know witch . Thanx for answer

Comment: Are you trying to create a 'Splash Page' then?  If so, http://drupal.org/project/splashify might help out.

Comment: Yes this is what I'm looking for but I didn't knew it's called like that . Thanks a lot .